# phonegap tabbar plugin cannot change page

Tags: cordova

I used PhoneGap NativeControls Plugins created a ios Tabbar, when I click a tabbar, it didn't change the view to the correspond html, following is my code, thanks for any help.

these functions is used to change pageview:

```js
function showFirstPage()
{
    window.location.href = 'firstTab.html';
}

function showSecondPage()
{
    window.location.href = 'secondTab.html';
}

function showThirdPage()
{
    window.location.href = 'thirdTab.html';
}

function showFourthPage()
{
    window.location.href = 'fourthTab.html';
}

function showFifthPage()
{
    window.location.href = 'fifthTab.html';
}
```

create a tabbar:

```js
function onBodyLoad()
{   
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
      // Initializating TabBar
    nativeControls = window.plugins.nativeControls;
    nativeControls.createTabBar();

    // 首页
    nativeControls.createTabBarItem(
                                "firstTab",
                                "首页",
                                "/www/tabs/tabbar1.png",
                                {"onSelect": function() {
                                //console.log("firstTab");
                                showFirstPage();
                                }}
                                );

// 版块
    nativeControls.createTabBarItem(
                                "secondTab",
                                "版块",
                                "/www/tabs/tabbar2.png",
                                {"onSelect": function() {
                                //console.log("secondTab");
                                showSecondPage();
                                }}
                                );

// 贴图
    nativeControls.createTabBarItem(
                                "thirdTab",
                                "贴图",
                                "/www/tabs/tabbar3.png",
                                {"onSelect": function() {
                                //console.log("thirdTab");
                                showThirdPage();
                                }}
                                );

// 个人中心
    nativeControls.createTabBarItem(
                                "fourthTab",
                                "个人中心",
                                "/www/tabs/tabbar4.png",
                                {"onSelect": function() {
                                //console.log("fourthTab");
                                showFourthPage();
                                }}
                                );

// 更多
    nativeControls.createTabBarItem(
                                "fifthTab",
                                "更多",
                                "/www/tabs/tabbar5.png",
                                {"onSelect": function() {
                                //console.log("fifthTab");
                                showFifthPage();
                                }}
                                );

    // Compile the TabBar
    nativeControls.showTabBar();
    nativeControls.showTabBarItems("firstTab", "secondTab", "thirdTab", "fourthTab", "fifthTab");
    nativeControls.selectTabBarItem("firstTab");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code if the change in Tab-bar doesn't change the page normally a Javascript error has stopped everything. I don't see why the code wouldn't work

Maybe try to work out the problem by using 'try-catch' http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_try_catch.asp

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you give me demo showing how to use the TabBar PhoneGap Plugin?  thank you very much.

Comment: if I change the function like this, it can print out the correspond info:    nativeControls.createTabBarItem(
                                    "firstTab",
                                    "首页",
                                    "/www/tabs/tabbar1.png",
                                    {"onSelect": function() {
                                    console.log("firstTab");
                                    }}
                                    );